# How to set git config values at runtime?

Tags: git, git-config

Is there a way to pass git config options to commands at runtime ?

Example use case:

The `git commit` command does not have a `-U` option (ie. `git diff`) to change context lines of `-v` verbose output, and the user does not want to set `diff.context` in config files.

Answer (score 2):

[`man git`](https://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/):

> `-c <name>=<value>`
>
> Pass a configuration parameter to the command. The value given will override values from configuration files. The  is expected in the same format as listed by git config (subkeys separated by dots).
>
> Note that omitting the `=` in `git -c foo.bar ...` is allowed and sets `foo.bar` to the boolean true value (just like `[foo]bar` would in a config file). Including the equals but with an empty value (like `git -c foo.bar= ...`) sets foo.bar to the empty string which `git config --type=bool` will convert to false.